# measuring mem / cpu on web server benchmark

Tags: php, nginx, benchmarking, cherokee

I'm evaluating static & php performance for some FOSS web servers,
they're all up an running fine.

I want to get RPS, ram- and cpu-usage.

any tool recommended,
(except the obvious, ab and gnuplot)

server OS: linux (ubuntu),
hammer OS: any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[top](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top) and [httpref](http://code.google.com/p/httperf/)

Comment: http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2005/04/http-performance-testing-with-httperf.html